# Problems Setting up custom logger in Python

Tags: python, logging

So I'm currently reworking our python based Automated Testing System (ATS) and I've come up against a real headache with logging. I've spent the last few hours going through youtube tutorials and articles on here, and I've yet to find a clear answer to my specific problem.

I want to replace all print statements with a logger that will output to both the console and .txt file. I've got the Test Log.txt creating (with datetime in the file name), but the file is blank and the printed text doesn't appear in the console either. This was using logger.debug. It's like the .txt file is being created before the text is ever passed to it.

I had originally been calling this via PrintLog.debug but that just led to visual studio telling me that the PrintLog.py had no attribute called debug. I'm really hoping I can just one bit of code that can be called by various scripts rather than having to bake it into every individual script. Additionally if you could also help me generate the logs in an 'OutputLogs' sub folder that would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import time
import datetime

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M - {fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

#Records Current date & time and appends it to the file namme of the txt log created at the end of this script.

import logging


def PrintLog(self):
    PrintLog = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    PrintLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s:%(asctime)s')

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(timeStamped('Test Report.txt'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    PrintLog.addHandler(file_handler)
    PrintLog.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

Edit: So to clarify, that's the logger but I want to call it and pass it information to it from another Python Script.

```
import os
import time
import sys
import subprocess
import datetime
import logging
from PrintLog import PrintLog



def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S - {fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

#Records Current date & time and appends it to the file namme of the txt log created at the end of this script.


from sys import platform
if platform == "darwin":
    PrintLog('Operating System = MAC')    
elif platform == "win32":
    PrintLog('Operating System = Windows')
```

Information such as the OS statements isn't passed to the PrintLog script.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this. If I put `logger.debug("Hello world")` at the end of that script and run it, I get output both on the console and in a file named `2022-06-07_19.48 - Test Report.txt`, as expected and desired.

Comment: Thanks for your response Thomas, I've updated my original post in order to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`logging.getLogger(__name__)` creates a new logger, not the same as the `logger` variable you created in your own log module, because `__name__` is different in each module.

Either import `logger` from your own module and use that, or configure the [root logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) instead:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()  # Without arguments, it gets the root logger.
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# ... add handlers etc. ...
```

Comment: Ok but if I use  `PrintLog.debug("Operating System = Windows")`
I get a "module 'PrintLog' has no attribute 'debug'" message.

Comment: So I've now set up PrintLog as a def object in the PrintLog.py.
This is then imported in the the main script with `from PrintLog import PrintLog`

And the text I want to send now formatted like this `PrintLog("Operating System = Windows")`

No error messages now but the text still doesn't get passed to the console or the .txt file.

Comment: I'm completely lost on what your code looks like now. What's a "def object"? You might want to read the [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) which might answer some of your questions.

Comment: Sorry, that's bad terminology on my part. I'll upload the updated code to the original post, so you can see what i'm seeing.